# What is the difference between Serial and Stream on the Arduino, and how is Serial.write implemented?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the difference between the terms Serial and Stream. Is Serial not a type of Stream?

I have questions on homework that I just don't understand.

Computers "read" the data they send each other by using (Streams or Serial?) to determine what each byte means?

Also, `Serial.write()` confuses me a lot too. It returns a byte of data, correct? A byte is 8 bits. So if an int type (16-bits) is passed to `Serial.write()` on the Arduino, it would return 2 bytes to the serial stream?

Similarly, if a variable is an unsigned long in Arduino C, how can we represent the most significant byte of this variable to the serial stream using `Serial.write()`?

For example, I have variable x as the unsigned long. Would `Serial.write(x>>8)` be the correct answer, because a long is 32 bits so unsigned makes it twice as big. Since `Serial.write()` returns in bytes, 64/8 would be 8.

All of these questions may seem really amateur, but I really want to learn this stuff and my teacher is not the best at explaining. If anyone can make this more clear conceptually, I will be eternally grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: no source code -> off-topic for `arduino` tag.  Also, unsigned does not make a variable twice as big.

Answer (score 6):

`Stream` is the base class that `Serial` inherits. `Serial` is a type of `Stream` but there are other types of Stream as well.

`write` is different from `print` in one important way: `write` sends things as raw bytes and `print` sends things as ASCII. So, if I `Serial.print(255)`, the Arduino will actually send out 3 bytes, the ASCII codes for all three digits. However, if I `Serial.write(255)` then the Arduino will send out one single byte with the value of `255` (`0b11111111`).

The number that `write` returns is the number of bytes that were written. It returns to the caller, not the serial stream. It tells the caller how many bytes got written.

> For example, I have a variable `x` as the `unsigned long`. Would `Serial.write(x>>8)` be the correct answer, because a `long` is 32 bits so `unsigned` makes it twice as big. Since `Serial.write()` returns in bytes, 64/8 would be 8

You have some very fundamental misunderstandings here. The unsigned version is the same 32 bits as the signed version.  It can hold a number twice as big because it doesn't need a sign bit, but it's got the same number of bits. To leave the MSB of a 32 bit quantity you need to shift right by 24 bits. Bitshifts are in bits, not bytes, so `myLong >> 24`.