# Difference between Serial.print() and Stream.print()

Tags: arduino, coding-style

I would like to know the difference between Serial functions and Stream functions in Ardiuno coding. Both behave in the same way but wat is the difference then?

Answer (score 2):

Stream is the base class that the Serial function inherits.

Copy/paste from the reference:
Stream defines the reading functions in Arduino. When using any core functionality that uses a read() or similar method, you can safely assume it calls on the Stream class. For functions like print(), Stream inherits from the Print class.

References:

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/

[What is the difference between Serial and Stream on the Arduino, and how is Serial.write implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965951/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-and-stream-on-the-arduino-and-how-is-seri)